# Mongoose - Model.deleteOne() is deleting the entire collection instead of a single document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a User model that contains an array of customers. I want to delete a specific customer based on the `customer _id`. From what I've read in the Mongoose docs, I should use `Model.deleteOne` to delete a single document.

**Here is my attempt**

User Schema (it's been shortened for brevity):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
    },
    registerDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    customer: [{
        name: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            default: 'No email name found'
        },
        fleet: [{
            unitNumber: {
                type: String,
                default: 'N/A',
            }
        }]
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Here is a look at the route and controller:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const customer_controller = require('../../controllers/customers');

router.delete('/customers/:custid', customer_controller.customer_remove);

  module.exports = router;
```

And finally the controller:

```
exports.customer_remove = (req, res) => {
    const { params } = req;
    const { custid } = params;

    User.deleteOne({ 'customer._id': custid }, (err) => {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        else 
            console.log(custid, 'is deleted');
    });
};
```

From what I thought, `User.deleteOne({ 'customer.id': custid })` would find the `customer _id` matching the `custid` that is passed in via the `req.params`. When I test this route in Postman, it deletes the entire `User` collection that the customer is found in, instead of just deleting the customer. Can I get a nudge in the right direction? I feel like I am close here (or not lol).

Answer (score 3):

`deleteOne` operates at the document level, so your code will delete the first `User` document that contains a `customer` element with a matching `_id`.

Instead, you want *update* the user document(s) to remove a specific element from the `customer` array field using [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull). To remove the customer from all users:

```
User.updateMany({}, { $pull: { customer: { _id: custid } } }, (err) => { ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I also misunderstood what exactly a document and element are.

Comment: In the callback parameters, I attempted to return the user like so (err, user) => {

Comment: Was able to get this implemented and working like I need. If you don't mind, I have one more question. In the callback, I attempted to return the user like so: `(err, user) => { res.send(user) }` and did return data, but it was not the user collection. In my update routes, I am able to return the `user` in the callback of `Model.update()`. Is this done differently for `Model.updateMany()`?

Comment: @maison.m Neither `update` nor `updateMany` provide the updated document to the callback. See `findOneAndUpdate` if you need that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Using Mongoose you can do this:

```
 model.findOneAndUpdate({ 'customer._id': custid }, {$pull: { $pull: { 
 customer: { _id: custid } }}, {new: true}).lean();
```

Removing subdocs.

Each sub document has an _id by default. Mongoose document arrays have a special id method for searching a document array to find a document with a given _id.

Visit: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

parent.children.id(_id).remove();

Answer (score 0):

Use async-await, may be that will work.

```
exports.customer_remove = async (req, res) => {
    const { params } = req;
    const { custid } = params;
    
    try {
        await User.deleteOne({ 'customer._id': custid });
        console.log(custid, 'is deleted');
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
};
```